# Can't see WebGrid element

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'd like to build a table with the helper WebGrid (MVC 4). I try to do it as shown below, but an error Failed to find name of type of namespace 'WebGrid' occurres, in spite of included namespace System.Web.Heplers in the code. Also IDE underlines the word "WebGrid" as something not proper.

I understand that there is some small mistake, but I'm confused with. Please, help me.

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication_test.Models.Customer>
@using System.Web.Helpers;

@{
    Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 5);
}
```

Comment: You're just assigning the `WebGrid` to a variable on your page. You haven't given Razor a place to use that variable and output it into the HTML sent to the browser.

Comment: There is just a part of code. Certainly, I use the method WebGrid.GetHtml(), but it doesn't give any results, because the compiler doesn't see the WebGrid.

Comment: Does closing and reopening Visual Studio resolve the issue? I have to use Visual Studio 2010 at work, and I see that type of issue with failing namespace resolution a lot. That usually will fix it for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, closing and reopening Visual Studio doesn't help (I use VS-2013)

Comment: Try it with the `@using` at the top?

Comment: I put @using to the top, closed and reopened VS, but.. nothing new.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution. It helped me in the same case for me.

Shortly - you need to add reference System.Web.Helpers to current project & reopen VStudio to accept changes.

[Picture-sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRygA.png)

Step by step:

1. Add reference to your project "System.Web.Helpers"

   - In your project right click on "References".
   - Select "Add reference..." in small menu.
   - In opened window go to Assemblies/Extensions.
   - Find & select in list "System.Web.Helpers" v2.0.0.0 (curent version on 10.16.2015).
   - Click OK to accept.
2. Add lib in the same dirrectory as your *.exe (~/bin/debug by default) to allow your project see it:

   - Rightclick on added reference in "References".
   - Select "Properties" in little menu.
   - Set property "Copy Local" to "true".
     [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLpx7.png)
3. Save changes;

   - Save changes in your Project.
   - Reopen VStudio & your project.

After that, you have to see the WebGrid object in View from System.Web.Helpers :)

If you don't - retry to add "@using" in View or... I dont know ;) This way helped for me.